# Kubuntu - Can't move/max/min windows

Tags: ubuntu, kde, kubuntu

All of a sudden it seems when ever I open a window on my Kubuntu (9.10) system, the windows dock in the upper left corner and can't be moved.  There is nor border on the windows, no min/max/close buttons in the upper right corner of the windows.  I tried opening a term window but it seems I can't type in the window.  Any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 3):

Loss of pointer focus and window decoration are clear symptoms for a `kwin` crash. Unlike other KDE applications, you will not get the crash manager.

If you still have the term window open, you can attempt to revive it by copying/pasting the characters k, w, i, n and a newline with the mouse. When it crashes again, you will see the reason in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I see this too on a fresh install of Kubuntu 14.04.3 (current LTS).  Not a very flash start...

In this case at least it's an Intel graphics/Mesa problem.

As reported at the link below, a workaround is to disable OpenGL, via:

System Setting / Desktop effects / Advanced / Compositing type: XRender

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=185650